# Android - SafetyNet Safe Browsing API

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services

Just trying to implement SafetyNet Safe Browsing API in an Android app and also read the documentation on : https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/safebrowsing.html but i am unable to reference `SafetyNet class`

E.g : They say on documentation :

> To use the Safe Browsing API, you must initialize the API by calling
>   initSafeBrowsing() and waiting for it to complete. The following code
>   snippet provides an example:
>
> `Tasks.await(SafetyNet.getClient(this).initSafeBrowsing())`

I have searched for this API lib to reference `SafetyNet` class object but i am unable to reference it.

I have tried to add in my build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-safebrowsing:v4-rev20190923-1.30.3'
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But still unable to find that class.

Anyone know how to implement this lib helper?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, such a amateur mistake :D .....

Instead of

```
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-safebrowsing:v4-rev20190923-1.30.3'
```

I should use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
```

But they didn't mention that on the official documentations :D, hope to be useful for anyone when being confuse sometimes

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the dependency package of safetynet. You can refer to the example code of safetynet on GitHub:

> https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet/blob/master/client/java/SafetyNetSample/Application/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:$google_play_services_version"
}
```

Definition of google_play_services_version：

```
ext.google_play_services_version = '11.0.1'
```